# another "can't save multiple checkbox" and "must be of the type array, string given"

Tags: laravel

I have seen many same question about this problem but I can't figure out how to fix mine

so I'm trying to save multiple checkbox and I think this one will work but now I get "must be of the type array, string given".

By the way this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  // $multi = Multi::create($request->only(['data'])->implode(', '));
  // $multi = Multi::select('data')->implode();

  $multis = implode(',', $request->get('data'));
  $multis = Multi::create(['data' => $request->get('data')]);

  return redirect()->route('multi.create')->with('success', 'berhasil.');
```

and this is my create.blade.php

```
                  @foreach($multis as $multi)
              {{$multi['data']}}<br>
              @endforeach
              <br>----------------<br>

              {{Form::open(['action'=>'MultiController@store'])}}
              {{Form::checkbox('data[]','A')}}A<br>
              {{Form::checkbox('data[]','B')}}B<br>
              {{Form::checkbox('data[]','C')}}C<br>
              {{Form::submit('TAMBAH')}}
              {{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: What is the `Multi` class? Is it a library (then provide a link) or a self-made class (then provide the code)?

Comment: My guess is `Multi` is a model.

Comment: ohh right, im sorry.... and yes multi ismodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$multis = implode(',', $request->data));
$multis = Multi::create(['data' => $multis]);
```

Comment: uhhh sir i got new problem...
sooo your code work if when i insert multiple checkbox for 1field, and im trying to insert 4 multiple field now and cant find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add fields name as a key of array and define all the data into different variables like this this will work.

```
    $multis1 = implode(',', $request->d);
    $multis2 = implode(',', $request->i);
    $multis3 = implode(',', $request->s);
    $multis4 = implode(',', $request->c);
    $multis= Test::create(array('d' =>  $multis1,'i' => $multis2,'s' => $multis3,'c' => $multis4));
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer i got another problem but its not from the implode i think, ill try to figure it out
thank you very much